# undefined function 'concat' vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, concatenation

I'm having a problem in concatenating 2 columns in my sql. Can someone check what went wrong in my concat statement.

Query:

```
Public Function getStudents(ByVal oStudentsBO As StudentsBO) As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable
    sql = "SELECT [KY_ID_NUM] as [ID Num], [NM_NICK] as [Nick Name], [CD_AGE_GROUP] as [Age Group], " &
          "[NM_LAST] as [Last Name], [NM_FIRST] as [First Name], " &
          "CONCAT(NM_GFIRST, NM_GLAST) FROM [tblStudents] " &
          "WHERE [NM_FIRST] Like '%" & oStudentsBO.NM_FIRST & "%'" &
          "OR [NM_NICK] LIKE '%" & oStudentsBO.NM_NICK & "%'" &
          "OR [NM_LAST] Like '%" & oStudentsBO.NM_LAST & "%'"
    dt = oDA.getDataTable(sql)
    Return dt
End Function
```

Error:

[image: error report]

Comment: which DBMS and version are you using? And please, copy and paste your code as text

Comment: What's the underline database?

Comment: what do you meant by underline database?

Comment: Oracle (which version 10g, 11g, 12g), MySql (which version), SQLServer, etc. I guess SQLServer from the query.

Comment: Could you also give us the table structure? I mean NM_GFIRST and NM_GLAST are of which type (varchar, char, text)

Comment: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, using MS ACCESS as my database and both are text

Comment: MS access don't have a CONCAT function. Use string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't have a function CONCAT. Instead, you must use a string concatenation:

```
Public Function getStudents(ByVal oStudentsBO As StudentsBO) As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable
    sql = "SELECT [KY_ID_NUM] as [ID Num], [NM_NICK] as [Nick Name], [CD_AGE_GROUP] as [Age Group], " &
          "[NM_LAST] as [Last Name], [NM_FIRST] as [First Name], " &
          " [NM_GFIRST] & [NM_GLAST] FROM [tblStudents] " &
          "WHERE [NM_FIRST] Like '%" & oStudentsBO.NM_FIRST & "%'" &
          "OR [NM_NICK] LIKE '%" & oStudentsBO.NM_NICK & "%'" &
          "OR [NM_LAST] Like '%" & oStudentsBO.NM_LAST & "%'"
    dt = oDA.getDataTable(sql)
    Return dt
End Function
```